# Stuck at Error 537 and Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql

Code:

```
With TempSalesOrder as
    (SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('(',[item]) > 0 
            THEN TRIM(LEFT([item],CHARINDEX('(',[item])-1)) 
            ELSE Trim([Item])
        END as 'Trimmed_Name',
        SUM(QTY) as 'Total_Sum'
    FROM temp.QB_SO
    GROUP BY [item], TRIM(LEFT([item],CHARINDEX('(',[item])-1)))
```

Please help. Im trying to trim the Item name by cutting out the extra information in the parenthesis. However, there are some without any extra info or the Parenthesis.

Comment: Here are some Example of my data from [Item] Column.

Comment: item
------------------------
Misc. Adjustment (Miscellaneous Adjustments)
-------------------------------------------  
Misc. Adjustment (Miscellaneous Adjustments)     
--------------------------------------------
P:Tools:Salon:MANN1092 (Practice Mannequin 14")

Comment: the `GROUP BY` should be `GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('(',[item]) > 0 
            THEN TRIM(LEFT([item],CHARINDEX('(',[item])-1)) 
            ELSE Trim([Item])
        END`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

the `GROUP BY` should be `GROUP BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(',[item]) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT([item],CHARINDEX('(',[item])-1)) ELSE Trim([Item]) END` – Lamak x mins ago

THANK YOU LAMAK!